# Cannot assign to the result of this expression

Tags: ios, swift

I am subclassing a uiscrollview and in the layoutSubviews method I have the following

```
let v = self.delegate?.viewForZoomingInScrollView!(self)
let f = v?.frame

if f != nil {
f!.origin.x = 100
}
```

I'm getting the error:

```
Cannot assign to the result of this expression
```

on the line

```
f!.origin.x = 100
```

Where am I going wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your code `f` is declared as an immutable variable. Immutable variables cannot be changed after initial assignment at declaration.

```
 let variable_name = 10 
 variable_name = 11 // Cannot assign to let value 'v'
```

The `let` keyword is used to declare immutable variables.
The `var` keyword is used to declare mutable variables.

```
 var variable_name = 10 
 variable_name = 14 // Can be changed
```

So change your code to `var f = v?.frame`.

Also if you trying to modify the frame of the view, it will only work if you directly assign to the `view?.frame.origin.x = 100`, since the above code will only create a copy of the frame in `f`.

Answer (score 1):

Because `f` is declared as `let` and immutable.